# Python Vigenere Cipher with required functions

Tags: python, caesar-cipher, vigenere

I am working on an online course that has us creating a caesar cipher and vigenere cipher, but we first created two functions; one to find the position of a letter in an alphabet variable, and one to rotate one given character a given amount of times (I have seen that ord() and chr() work better, but the assignment wants us to focus on simpler concepts for now, I guess).

I was able to get the caesar function working, but am unsure as how to go forward with the vigenere cipher. I have watched many videos and looked around this site, but have not found any that allow for the preservation of spaces and non alphabetical characters. Can anyone point me in the right direction of how to start the vigenere function?

```
#Create function alphabet_position(letter) to turn letter into number
#such as a=0 or e=4, using lowercase to make sure case doesnt matter.
def alphabet_position(letter):
    alphabet ="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" #Lists alphabet for a key
    lower_letter = letter.lower()   #Makes any input lowercase.
    return alphabet.index(lower_letter) #Returns the position of input as a number.

def rotate_character(char, rot):
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    if char.isalpha():
        a = alphabet_position(char)
        a = (a + rot) % 26            #needs modulo
        a = (alphabet[a])
        if char.isupper():
            a = a.title()
        return a
    else:
       return char

def encrypt(text, rot):
    list1 = ""
    for char in text:
        list1 += rotate_character(char, rot)
    return list1



def main():
    x = input("Type a message: ")
    y = input("Rotate by: ")
    #result = rotate_character(x, y)  #Not needed once encrypt function works.
    result = encrypt(x, y)
    print (result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: make your alphabet cover any character you want; do addition `% len(alphabet)`. encryption with `rot`; decryption with `len(alphabet)-rot`.

Comment: Where are you saying I should put the modulo Len(alphabet)?  Within my current  encrypt function?

Comment: in `rotate_character` instead of `% 26`...

Comment: Thank you very much, I will test that as soon as possible.  I'm new to this site, can I upvote comments?

Comment: wanted to make sure it worked - had to test it out therefore and pasted as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following my comments; using all printables as alphabet:

```
from string import ascii_letters, digits, punctuation, whitespace

ALPHABET = ascii_letters + digits
STATIC_ALPHABET = punctuation + whitespace

# minor speedup
ALPHA_INDEX = {a: i for i, a in enumerate(ALPHABET)}
STATIC_ALPHABET_SET = set(STATIC_ALPHABET)
MOD = len(ALPHABET)

def encrypt(char, key):
    if char in STATIC_ALPHABET_SET:
        return char
    else:
        return ALPHABET[(ALPHA_INDEX[char] + key) % MOD]

def decrypt(char, key):
    if char in STATIC_ALPHABET_SET:
        return char
    else:
        return ALPHABET[(ALPHA_INDEX[char] + MOD - key) % MOD]

key = 17
plain = 'Hello World!'
enc = ''.join(encrypt(char, key) for char in plain)
print(enc)  # YvCCF dFICu!
dec = ''.join(decrypt(char, key) for char in enc)
print(dec)  # Hello World!
```

Comment: The assignment makes us use the alphabet as a string, so I'm guessing I can substitute what you have me for my string?  Also, I have not run into''.join before.  Is that just adding all the parts back into one string?

Comment: yes & yes. just try to insert any alphabet you want.

Comment: I tried your answer, and for the most part it works, but unfortunately the assignment wants us to preserve the non alphabetical characters.  So the ! would remain an ! even when encrypted, as would a space.

Comment: ok, updated. the characters in `STATIC_ALPHABET` will no go unchanged. (and by the way `ALPHABET` and  `STATIC_ALPHABET` both are strings).

Comment: Thank you so much!